# Replacing a Groovy XML Node causes problems in subsequents findAll calls

Tags: groovy, xml-parsing, findall

I use groovy to parse a XML file using XmlParser. Just to avoid the handling of namespace prefixes, I used xmlRoot.'**'.findAll() method to find some nodes. The sample code shows how it works correctly until I just read the nodes, because each item passed to the closure is a Node object. But when I change the contents of a node (in this case, just the text of the node), the next call to findAll does not iterate on Node objects. For each character I put in the text, a String object is passed to the closure. I solved it checking the type with instanceof, but it seems to be that this is a bug.

Am I doing something wrong or it's a bug?

```
 class XmlParserTest {

static final String XML_SAMPLE = """
<ns0:root xmlns:ns0="mycompany.com">
    <ns0:firstParent>
        <ns0:item1>uppercase_me!</ns0:item1>
    </ns0:firstParent>
    <ns0:secondParent>
        <ns0:item2>uppercase_me_too!/ns0:item2>
    </ns0:secondParent>
</ns0:root>
"""

    static void main(String[] args) {
        def xmlRoot = new XmlParser(false, false).parseText(XML_SAMPLE)

        //******* find item1 and capitalize its text ********
        def nds1 = xmlRoot.'**'.findAll {
            it.name().equals("ns0:item1")
        }

        Node nd1 = nds1[0]

        //This changes the text of the node, but something strange happens to the node tree
        nd1.setValue(nd1.value().toString().toUpperCase())

        //The same problem happens using replaceNode() instead of setValue()
        //Node newNode = new Node(nd1.parent(), nd1.name(), nd1.value().toString().toUpperCase())
        //nd1.replaceNode(newNode)

        //******* find item2 and capitalize its text ********
        def nds2 = xmlRoot.'**'.findAll {
            //for each character in the string "uppercase me!" a String is passed instead of Node
            //As String doesn't have a name method, an exception is raised
            it.name().equals("ns0:item2")

            //using instanceof fixes the problem, at least for this case
            it instanceof Node && it.name().equals("ns0:item2")
        }

        Node nd2 = nds2[0]
        nd2.setValue(nd2.value().toString().toUpperCase())

        assert nd1.value().toString() == nd1.value().toString().toUpperCase()
        assert nd2.value().toString() == nd2.value().toString().toUpperCase()
    }

}
```

Comment: not clear what do you want to do. uppercase all text in nodes with some names?

Comment: and what does it mean `something strange happens to the node tree` ? what exactly the problem?

Comment: it means that if you think to node.findAll() as a tree traversal, you'll se that, for each character in the string, you receive a call with "it" parameter that is not a node, but a string with the character.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened an issue on Groovy: [this is the explation on what happened](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-9048)